# Swift: what is the right way to split up a [[CGFloat]] resulting in a [[[CGFloat]]] with a given subarray size?

Tags: ios, swift

Starting with a large `[[CGFloat]]`, what is the best way I could go about splitting up this array into smaller arrays by condition?

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[9999,9999],[6,1],[5,6],[9999,9999],[6,1],[11,6],[21,3]]
```

split the array with `[9999,9999]`

the result is  `[[[1,2],[2,3]],[[6,1],[5,6]],[[6,1],[11,6],[21,3]]]`

I can use `for`  to achieve it ,but I want to know a best way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split` function can also be used with nested arrays

```
let array = [[1,2],[2,3],[9999,9999],[6,1],[5,6],[9999,9999],[6,1],[11,6],[21,3]]
let split = array.split{ $0 == [9999,9999] }.map{Array($0)}
```